# jquery slicknav unroll onload

Tags: jquery, addclass, removeclass, slicknav

I am using the slicknav jquery mobile menu for a project. On initial page load, all 3 of the menus are rolled up. I would like the 2nd menu item to be unrolled, and menu items 1 & 3 to be rolled up as they are by default. I assume I need to fiddle with the jquery, but I can't get it to work as of yet. I put it on jsfiddle so you can see the basics of what I am trying to do.

jsfiddle.net/MexicaliBill/u0h38erd/14/

Any ideas? Thanks,

Bill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this works :

```
$('.slicknav_collapsed').eq(1).removeClass('slicknav_collapsed').addClass('slicknav_open').find($('.slicknav_open ul')).eq(0).removeAttr('class').slideDown().attr('aria-hidden', 'false');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u0h38erd/29/

Update - wrote a small loop to rename the main `li` items with an id :

```
var relevant = $('ul').eq(0).children($('li.slicknav_parent'));

$.each(relevant, function(key) {
$(this).attr('id', 'menu' + (key+1));
});
```

Then the menu in question can be targeted with it's id :

```
$('#menu2').removeClass('slicknav_collapsed').addClass('slicknav_open').find($('.slicknav_open ul')).eq(0).removeAttr('class').slideDown().attr('aria-hidden', 'false');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u0h38erd/39/

Comment: Hi- Thanks for looking into this. What you suggested almost works, but I wanted the sub-menu to still be rolled up on initial load. In the example you gave the sub-menu is unrolled also. Sorry I didn't explain that in the initial description because it is a little confusing but I put it in the text of the jsfiddle example.

Comment: Okay, didn't get that at first. Tweaked it and think it's up to the spec now. :-)

Comment: Almost there. Is there a way to do it using ids? The reason I ask is because just now I was testing it, and if the first menu has a sub-menu, then that gets unrolled by default and the second menu is rolled up using your current code (see jsfiddle.net/MexicaliBill/u0h38erd/37/ since it is hard to explain). My actual menu is quite long and if I have to rely on the count, it could get thrown off if the menu gets changed slightly.

Comment: Solving this looked quite troublesome at first because the original ids get stripped when it's cloned. But I found a workaround by looping through the relevant list items and adding an id again. Answer was updated with this. Cheers.